# Is EmblemJS the thing I should be using in a new EmberJS app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, emblem.js

I am building an Ember app with a Rails 4 JSON back-end. I am using the 'ember-rails' gem which embedded the Ember dir structure into the Rails app--which I like. It also included EmblemJS which I saw in action in this tutorial: http://ember.vicramon.com/

My question surrounds whether Emblem is going to be around for awhile and concerning the wisdom of building an app with it. Is this something I will be happy I did a year from now or should I rip it out and stick with Handlebars and HTML?

Comment: Since Alex is a member of the Ember core team and has stated that compatibility with the upcoming HTMLBars won't be an issue, I think you're pretty safe. That said, this question really isn't a good fit for SO so I'm voting to close.

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was wondering about but hadn't found that statement, I guess. Thanks for the response.

Comment: BTW, I posted here knowing it was not ideal for SO--I (mis)understood that this is where Ember community questions are to be directed.

Comment: [Here's Alex's statement about HTMLbars on the github repo](https://github.com/machty/emblem.js/issues/139). As for the suitability of the question, it's more that it [doesn't fit the format well](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) than it being related to Ember. Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As supplied by @steveax in the question's comment, Emblem will be supported when HTMLBars comes out. This suggests longevity for EmblemJS.